# How to load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"?

Tags: node.js, powershell, windows-10

I tried to run "VCBuild.exe"

My environment:

- Windows 10 Pro X64
- node v7.9.0-x64
- Visual Studio 2017

So,I've just run like this command.

```
 $npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

But it doesn't work.
Errors are bellow:

```
> windows-build-tools@1.2.1 postinstall C:\Users\Josephine\AppData\Roaming\npm\n       ode_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./lib/index.js

Downloading BuildTools_Full.exe
[>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
Downloading python-2.7.11.msi
[>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
Downloaded python-2.7.11.msi. Saved to C:\Users\Josephine\.windows-build-tools\p       ython-2.7.11.msi.
Starting installation...
Please restart this script from an administrative PowerShell!
The build tools cannot be installed without administrative rights.
To fix, right-click on PowerShell and run "as Administrator".
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\Josephine\AppD       ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules'
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\Josephine\A       ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules'
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\Josephine\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\win       dows-build-tools\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\       node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--global" "--production" "windows       -build-tools"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! windows-build-tools@1.2.1 postinstall: `node ./lib/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the windows-build-tools@1.2.1 postinstall script 'node ./lib/       index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the windows-build-tools p       ackage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./lib/index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs windows-build-tools
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls windows-build-tools
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Josephine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-26T17_33       _28_317Z-debug.log
```

how can i fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output says exactly what you need to do:

> Please restart this script from an administrative PowerShell!
>   The build tools cannot be installed without administrative rights.
>   To fix, right-click on PowerShell and run "as Administrator".

If you run PowerShell (or the Command Prompt you used to run `npm`) as Administrator, then it should work.

Comment: Ok. it does work. but another error appears. So can you solve that error, too?